# Javascript textbox validation RegEx - Multiple integers (0 <= int <= 500), separated ONLY with single whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want:
#1 *array* (the length is 100, *keydown* will be blocked if it is already 100 *white space*s)

> 0 100 199 2 129 500 11 14 499

or
#2 just an *integer*

> 499

So, **one** *White space* is the only *separator*. *First* character must not be *white space*. **Last** character can either be *white space* or *number*

---

```
return /^\d*$/.test(value) && (value === "" || parseInt(value) <= 500
```

so I tried the above function (only 1 integer) and these RegEx too:

```
/^(?=.*\d)[\d ]+$/
/^(\s*[0-9]+\s*)+$/
```

Sadly, those two did not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the regex you are looking for!

```
var regex = /^(\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|500) ?){1,100}$/;
return regex.test(value);
```

Explanation

- Match numbers within the range [0, 500]:
  `\b([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|500)\b`
- Add the conditional empty space after the number: `(\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|500)\b ?)`
- Add quantifier {1, 100} (1 to 100 matches): `(\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|500)\b ?){1,100}`
- Assert the condition for the entire line: `^(\b([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-4][0-9]{2}|500)\b ?){1,100}$`

Comment: I tried your answer in regex101.
Well done, sir. This is out of my league (unless there are some explanation step-by-step—would be much appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

You can also split on whitespace and then filter

```
input.split(" ").filter(n => n >= 0 && n <= 500)
```